# How do BLE IoT devices usually generate their private MAC addresses?

Tags: random, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

Are there any common ways for a BLE IoT device to generate its resolvable/non-resolvable private device addresses?

For example, it seems that in BR/EDR (classic Bluetooth) the spec demands the use of FIPS PRNGs, but I don't see the recommended/compulsory/popular ways to generate the 24-bit *prand* in resolvable private device addresses on Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral devices.

I wonder if resource constraints would stop IoT devices from using FIPS PRNGs. The results I found so far on MAC randomization are all about BLE on mobile devices...

Answer (score 1):

The generation of a resolvable private address is described in the [Bluetooth Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) v5.2, Vol 6, Part B, Section 1.3.2.2 (Private device address generation):

> To generate a resolvable private address, the device must have either
> the Local Identity Resolving Key (IRK) or the Peer Identity Resolving
> Key (IRK). The resolvable private address shall be generated with the
> IRK and a randomly generated 24-bit number. The random number is known
> as prand and shall meet the following requirements:
>
> - At least one bit of the random part of prand shall be 0
> - At least one bit of the random part of prand shall be 1

[image]

The hash itself is generated using the following formula:-

> hash = ah(IRK, prand)

Where ah is a random address hash function defined in the Bluetooth Specification v5.2, Vol 3, Part H, Section 2.2.2. You are right, there aren't any recommendations for generating the prand apart from the requirements above, so this is left to the user.

As for the non-resolvable address, this is explained in the same section:-

> To generate a non-resolvable address, the device shall generate a
> 48-bit address with the following requirements:
>
> - At least one bit of the random part of the address shall be 1
> - At least one bit of the random part of the address shall be 0
> - The address shall not be equal to the public address

[image]

These are some useful links that describe BLE privacy in general:-

- [Bluetooth Addresses in Privacy in BLE](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/)
- [How Privacy Works in BLE](http://lpccs-docs.dialog-semiconductor.com/Tutorial-DA145x-BLE-Security/privacy.html)
- [Bluetooth Devices Addresses](https://www.programmersought.com/article/9026830547/)

Comment: These are just about the formats of the generated device addresses. An interesting thing is that when you start your journey from [Vol 6] Part B, Sec. 6.1 the Resolvable Private Address generation interval, you'll probably get stuck in the loop of [Vol 6] Part B, Sec. 1.3.2.2: private device address generation -> [Vol 3] Part H, Sec. 2.2.2: random address hash function -> [Vol 3] Part C, Sec. 10.8.2.1 the Non-Resolvable Private Address generation procedure (-> [Vol 6] Part B, Section 1.3.2.2: private device address generation).

Comment: I am interested in the commonly used (pseudo)random number generators behind this security provision and the reasons for their use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most platforms just take whatever secure number generator that is available. May it be a "true number generator" directly or a csprng seeded by such a one. A trng on Bluetooth chips can for example be based on radio background noise. See https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.nrf52832.ps.v1.1/rng.html?cp=4_2_0_25#concept_h35_c1l_cs for nRF52832.

Comment: I would like to know the deterministic ways to stuff or extend the raw entropy to the 22-bit or 46-bit random part of BLE MAC. According to a MobiQuitus 2019 paper, now the generation intervals of these private addresses can be lower than one second, and I doubt if the entropy source itself in the IoT settings can produce that much true randomness. Any concrete BLE IoT use of FIPS-compliant PRNGs?